# Java Mongo DB Unable to get valid next id

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am trying insert an item in MongoDB using Java MongoDB driver.Before inserting I am trying to get nextId to insert,but not sure why I am always getting nextId as 4 .I am using below given method to get nextId before inserting any item in Mongo.

```
 private Long getNextIdValue(DBCollection dbCollection) {

    Long nextSequenceNumber = 1L;

    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("id", -1);

    DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find().sort(query).limit(1);

    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject itemDBObj = cursor.next();
        nextSequenceNumber = new Long(itemDBObj.get("id").toString()) + 1;
    }

    return nextSequenceNumber;
}
```

I have total 13 record in my mongodb collection.What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: use  db.collection.count() to get the number of documents in collection and incremented the result by 1 to get the nextId

Comment: You are strongly advised **not** to use an incrementing integer for your document id; the [official guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#considerations) says "_Generally in MongoDB, you would not use an auto-increment pattern for the _id field, or any field, because it does not scale for databases with large numbers of documents._".

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do that. You don't need create a bad management id situation as the driver already do this in the best way, just use the right type and annotation for the field:

```
@Id
@ObjectId
private String id;
```

Then write a generic method to insert all entites:

```
public T create(T entity) throws MongoException, IOException {

    WriteResult<? extends Object, String> result = jacksonDB.insert(entity);

    return (T) result.getSavedObject();
}
```

This will create a time-based indexed hash for id's which is pretty much more powerful than get the "next id".

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_objectid.htm

Comment: I need numeric custom auto-increment Id as 1,2,3,4

Comment: You won't be able to use it as either "id" or "_id"  because it's related with internal driver implementations.  So if you want to create another named "ordinal" or anything. But just don't try to force the wrong way to work with id's in a NoSQL context. You are trying to come with relational database concepts. It just different

Answer (score 0):

How can you perform Arithmetic operations like +1 to String

```
 nextSequenceNumber = new Long(itemDBObj.get("id").toString()) + 1;
```

Try to create a Sequence collection like this.

```
{"id":"MySequence","sequence":1}
```

Then use Update to increment the id

```
// Query for sequence collection
Query query = new Query(new Criteria().where("id").is("MySequence"));

//Increment the sequence by 1
Update update = new Update();
update.inc("sequence", 1);

FindAndModifyOptions findAndModifyOptions = new FindAndModifyOptions();
findAndModifyOptions.returnNew(true);

SequenceCollection sequenceCollection = mongoOperations.findAndModify(query, update,findAndModifyOptions, SequenceCollection.class);
return sequenceModel.getSequence();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the work around using b.collection.count().I simply find the total count and incremented by 1 to assign id to my object.